# XSLT - Detecting text between elements

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am working on a transform to wrap consecutive elements of the same type into a single element, but only if there is no text between the nodes.

For example:

```
<foo>ABC</foo><foo>DEF</foo> <foo>GHI</foo>
  <foo>JKL</foo>
```

Should transform to:

```
<bar>
  <foo>ABC</foo>
  <foo>DEF</foo>
  <foo>GHI</foo>
  <foo>JKL</foo>
</bar>
```

Whitespace should be ignored whether it is a space or a return. Any other text should indicate an end to what should be wrapped. For example:

```
<foo>ABC</foo><foo>DEF</foo> some text in between <foo>GHI</foo>
  <foo>JKL</foo>
```

Should transform to:

```
<bar>
  <foo>ABC</foo>
  <foo>DEF</foo>
</bar> some text in between 
<bar>
  <foo>GHI</foo>
  <foo>JKL</foo>
</bar>
```

I have tried selecting the `<foo>` element using:

```
foo[following-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space()='']]
```

But this is not picking up the case where there is a space between the `<foo>` elements. (There are additional criteria in the full template match, but this is the part that is not working as I expect.

I wrote a test transform to output the value of using the `normalize-space` function on the text following the element, and it outputs a single space for the lines where there is a space between the elements. However, if I query for:

```
foo[following-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space()=' ']]
```

It does not find those elements. So, I'm totally confused.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you use an XSLT 2.0 processor (with `for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::foo | self::text()[not(normalize-space())])"`)?

Comment: I've tried using `[not(normalize-space())]` in the selection, and it has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2.0 you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="*[foo]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::foo | self::text()[not(normalize-space())])">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                        <bar>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </bar>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ncntCSS

Comment: Thanks. I will look into modifying this for my specific case which is actually more complicated. I have an element in between each `<foo>`, rather than actual adjacent `<foo>` elements. So I actually need to look for `<foo> <baz> <foo>` etc. And I need to keep single `<foo>` from being wrapped in `<bar>`.

Comment: Turns out the issue with `[not(normalize-space())]` seeming to not work was because there were non-breaking spaces instead of regular spaces in a couple places. I updated the template match to use `[not(normalize-space(translate(.,'&#160;', ' ')))]` and it worked. I do prefer the grouping method over my old transform though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with `[normalize-space()='']` or `[not(normalize-space())]` seeming to not work was because there were non-breaking spaces instead of regular spaces in a couple places. I updated the template match to use `[not(normalize-space(translate(.,'&#160;', ' ')))]` and it worked.